# description instead of "-"

Tags: sql-server, procedure

I have sp .. in this i try when descitem value has "-" then want to get value @Typeid
what ever in this parameter i try this

before modify

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetItem
    @Typeid Smallint
As
    begin
        select 0 Itemid, '-' descitem
        union all
        select ci.Itemid, ci.descitem descitem
        from Item ci where ci.Typeid=@Typeid 
    END
return
```

when i execute this shows result like this

```
 exec GetItem 38

    Itemid  descitem
       0      -
```

and if i try with another like

```
 exec GetItem 39
 Itemid descitem
   0        -
   83      issues
   84       system
   85       repair
```

after modify

```
   ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetItem
    @Typeid Smallint
As
begin
    declare @descitem nvarchar(50) 
        select 0 Itemid, '-' descitem
        union all
        select ci.Itemid, ci.descitem descitem
        from Item ci where ci.Typeid=@Typeid 
        if @descitem='-'
    begin
        select Typeid, descitem descitem from Type
    end
    END
return
```

so i want when i execute

```
 exec GetItem 38
```

then want to get description of 38  instead of "-"

**UPDATE**

```
tables

    **type table**
typeid descitem      catg_id
1      fruits       4
2      suggestions  5
3      reports      6

**item table**

itemid   descitem   catg_id   typeid
1        good        5         2
2        bad         5         2
3        average     5         2
4        report1     6         3
5        report2     6         3
```

so as mentioned that there is no **4 catg_id** in item table 
so want there is fruit in typeid then want to display also in result
when i execute **getitem 4**

```
item descitem
0     fruits
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant tables DDL, some sample data as DML and desired results.

Comment: @ZoharPeled check update please

Comment: @cooluser in the end, are you searching by `catg_id` or `typeid`? your code is using @typeid whils your descriptive example is about filtering by `catg_id=4`.

Comment: sorry instead of catg_id use typeid .. @IvanStarostin

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear if you are searching items by category id (as suggested from the text) or by type if (as suggested from the query).

I went with category id as suggested from the text:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetItem
    @CategoryId Smallint
As
BEGIN

    SELECT Itemid, descitem descitem
    FROM Item
    WHERE catg_id = @CategoryId 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 0, descitem
    FROM type
    WHERE catg_id = @CategoryId 
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Item 
        WHERE catg_id = @CategoryId 
    )

END
```

The where clause of the second query will cause it to only return results when there are no items with the category id you are searching.